# Disable HTML asp textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, textbox

When I use a HTML-element in my textboxes I was getting this error:

[image]

To fix this error, I did this:

1. Adding `ValidateRequest="false"` at the top of the .aspx page.
2. Adding `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to the webconfig file.

After doing this, the error above didnt appear, and the HTML-elements that I used were shown with the markup.

For example: I used the `<b>Test</b>` elements in the textbox, and this was showed in a label as:

**Test**

But what I would like to have is, when someone adds HTML elements to my textbox, the error shouldn't appear, and the elements shouldn't be converted. So the label must show:

```
<b>Test</b> instead of Test (which is BOLD)
```

What can I do to make it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Server.HtmlEncode("<b>Test</b>")`